# quarter to five p.m

Tags: time, time-words

Can I add a.m and p.m to the time? But I have to write time in phrases. So for example:

> It's quarter to five p.m.

Is that right or not?

Comment: Just a personal opinion, but I find the juxtaposition of "colloquial" ***quarter to** [hour]* and "formal, official" ***p.m.*** quite jarring in the example as given. I'd much prefer either *It's quarter to five **in the afternoon*** or *It's **four forty-five** p.m.* (or go the whole hog with military time; ***It's sixteen forty-five***).

Comment: I would say if you want to use 'quarter to five' you should write 'in the morning' in full.

If you want to use A.M. or P.M. the you should revert to 'four fourty five A.M.'

Comment: Mariya, you can click on the `edit` label under your question if you'd like to include additional examples you're not sure about.

Comment: @userr2684291 just fyi, you can put the word edit within square brackets to make it even easier for mariya. Like so: [edit]

Answer (score 7):

My sense, from my own experience, is that people usually use the informal "in the morning" when using the casual "quarter to three" in words, and the more formal, technical-sounding "a.m." when using the precise "2:45" in numbers. If you're only mentioning an hour, of course, then there's no difference when speaking aloud, and either might be used.

However, while I say "usually", I suspect that that is not by a significant margin. There's nothing weird or unnatural about "quarter to three a.m." or "2:45 in the morning". Using both *about the same time* in *a single phrase* will make you look/sound silly, though. Don't say "2:45 a.m. in the morning"<sup>1</sup>. "From 9:15 in the morning to quarter to five p.m." is perhaps idiosyncratic, and might draw odd looks in a formal context, but is in no way *wrong*.

---

<sup>1</sup>: There will likely be edge cases where it's appropriate to say that, but it will arise naturally from the surrounding text - it's likely that, in most analyses, they wouldn't actually be the same phrase. "I'm leaving at 7 a.m. in the morning" could be better rephrased to avoid the apparent redundancy, in the case where it means "I'm leaving at 7 a.m. tomorrow". However, if you parse the apparently-redundant sentence with both "at 7 a.m." and "in the morning" as *separate* adverbials of time, you can see that *in the morning* and *a.m.* aren't part of the same phrase.

Comment: I agree the "aptness" of including relatively formal ***a.m. / p.m.*** varies somewhat according to whether it's coupled with (again, relatively formal) ***two forty-five*** or with (relatively informal) ***quarter to three***. I'm not sure if it would be possible to find statistical support in Google Books showing that usage skews in favour of what we both seem to think are the more "natural" combinations, but I certainly wouldn't rule that out. In which case arguably what we're saying would be a matter of "verifiable truth", rather than "personal opinions / stylistic preference".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, for me it's what my impression is, of what I've experienced. Utterly unverifiable, but also working with a lot of stuff that won't be on ngram.

Comment: Well, your later edit brings more attention to what I consider to be another relevant factor besides the "formal / informal clash". In some contexts, I can certainly see that ***in the morning** and **a.m.** aren't part of the same phrase.*

Answer (score 3):

From my initial comment, I personally find the juxtaposition of "colloquial" ***quarter to** [hour]* and "formal, official" ***p.m.*** quite jarring in the example as given. I'd much prefer either *It's quarter to five in the afternoon* or *It's four forty-five p.m.* (or go the whole hog with military time; *It's sixteen forty-five*).

But that's very much a personal opinion about style. As regards using both ***a.m. / p.m.*** (capitalised on not, with periods or not, according to stylistic preference) and ***in the morning / afternoon / evening***, consider...

> [*"at 7 am in the morning"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at%207%20am%20in%20the%20morning%22) - about 4510 written instances in Google Books

...where obviously there will be plenty more for the actual word ***seven***, or for other times. I believe it's relevant that in many (but by no means *all*) of those hits, *in the morning* will mean ***tomorrow** morning*. In which case it probably wouldn't even occur to most native speakers that there was any tautologous repetition at all (it simply clarifies the *day* of the specified *time*).

There's often also an element of (perfectly idiomatic / natural) *emphasis* in my example (either or both of ***a.m.*** and ***in the morning*** could be seen as implying *[unusually] **early***. This isn't so likely with ***p.m. + in the afternoon***, so you won't come across that collocation very often.

But the justification for "clarification / emphasis" certainly re-appears with...

> [*"at 7 pm in the evening"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at%207%20pm%20in%20the%20evening%22) - about 3960 hits in Google Books

Perhaps I should have switched to ***six** p.m.* there, to add weight to my point here. Suppose you hear one work colleague say to another, *I'll see you at 6 p.m. in the evening.* In context, it's extremely likely the speaker expects himself and/or the other person to *return home after work* before they meet again. Effectively, *in the evening* is an "additional clarification" element, used to distinguish "working afternoon" from "leisure time evening".

---

So as you should be able to see, there are contexts where it's absolutely fine to include *both* "time of day" elements. Arguably it's "clumsy" to do this unless you actually want either the nuance of "emphasis" OR the other associations *(**morning = early, evening = after work**)* involved.

Since it might be difficult for non-native speakers to reliably identify which contexts *do* justify the repetition, and it's undoubtedly true that there will be other more "neutral" contexts where it's noticeably "awkward" to include both, my general rule of thumb would be to avoid it. But if you think you have a context that seems to match the "valid" constructions I've referred to above, don't rule it out. And certainly don't feel you can justifiably criticise any native speaker who does it!

Comment: Oh wow! *Two* downvotes! This one could get interesting!

Comment: There seems to be a lot of helpful advice here, and, to your credit, you're not being dogmatic about anything. Count me among the upvoters. I'm curious about what the downvoters might have disagreed with. (One thing I will say, though, is that you overstate the number of hits on Google. Go to Page 2, and those 3960 hits dwindle down to 11. Still, this is very hard to gauge using Google, because there are twelve hours in a day that could all be used. [This query is a good one](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=mWSaXIqkM63l5gKasIjQBg&q="at+*+am+in+the+morning").)

Comment: btw - does "asterisk" (the symbol I can't actually *write* here in a comment) actually work in Google Internet searches? I seem to remember it doesn't in Google Books, but *does* in NGrams.

Comment: You can escape an asterisk in comments by putting a backslash in front of it (`\*` = \*). Yes, the asterisk works in Google Books, where it replaces any number of words, I believe. In the Google Books Ngram Viewer it replaces a single word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either A.M. or in the morning, and P.M. or in the evening. It is incorrect to use both **A.M.** and **in the morning** in the same sentence.

In your case, you would be correct in saying **It's a quarter to five P.M.**

Comment: ...but I must say that although *[early time] **a.m.** in the morning* sounds fine (particularly when it means ***...tomorrow** morning*, but that *needn't* be the case), I don't like the corresponding *at 3 p.m. in the afternoon* (but again, I see no problem with *at 3 p.m. **tomorrow** afternoon*).

Comment: ...sorry, but on reflection, the downvote stands. It's often ugly and unnecessary tautology to include both "temporal clarifiers", but they can have different nuances, and there are contexts where it's perfectly okay to include both. Your "incorrect" is an inaccurate sweeping generalisation.

Comment: A.M. and P.M. refer to a period within a day. Adding a phrase like **in the morning** or **in the afternooon** after A.M. or P.M. is redundant, and thus incorrect.

Comment: If I could downvote *comments*, I surely would! Where did you get the idea that redundancy is "incorrect" in English? It's *extremely* common (and *natural*, in many contexts).

Comment: Just because lots of people have used it in writing doesn't make it automatically correct. Look up "the dangerous of". That one occurs a lot, but it still isn't right.

Comment: Extremely common and natural do not equate to it being correct in the formal language. Everyone misuses phrases all the time in spoken/informal English, where issues like this are not a problem. However, formally, this phrase would be incorrect.

Comment: @LorelC.: Gimmie a break! By comparison with "the dangers of", ["the dangerous of"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dangerous+of%2Cthe+dangers+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20dangerous%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20dangers%20of%3B%2Cc0) barely exists!

Comment: medicine_man: - You are *wildly* incorrect in assuming some "formal" set of rules justifying your position here. But I guess there's no point in me keep shouting about it if you're set in your position. I'll just have to write my own answer and let others vote on the matter.

Comment: "Four a.m. in the morning/Carried away by a moonlight shadow" - Mike Oldfield

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No problem in that usage. Make sure both a.m. and p.m. are properly written in lowercase with periods.

I have found an example sentence from [NY Times website](https://cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/03/20/the-mysterious-330-a-m-roof-parties/):

> Over the past two weeks, however, a group of hooligans have made a routine of partying on my roof at 3:30 a.m.

And here's another one from [Slate](https://slate.com/culture/2018/06/oscar-wilde-weighs-in-on-donald-trumps-policy-of-separating-families-at-the-borders.html), showing something more akin to your example:

> No prisoner is allowed under any circumstances to leave his cell after half-past five p.m.

Comment: The punctuation of *AM* is not universally agreed upon, and largely depends on which style guide you subscribe to.

Comment: Lutfur Rahman - "properly written" for the UK _Guardian_ is 1am, 6.30pm, full stop between hour and minute figures. No spacing, lower case, no "periods" in am or pm. Beware of assuming that a local convention (or what you are used to) is a universal rule.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2005/dec/19/mainsection.international1) *...the school opened its doors **at 7 am***. That's just the first example I saw from a site-specific search (second, actually; the first was a user comment, not journalist's copy). But maybe that's just showing us why we used to call it *The **Grauniad*** :) There seem to be plenty of examples with both orthographies.

Comment: Yes, journalists do disregard their publication's style guide. You should take a look at some of the stuff in the _Daily Express_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'll be seeing a journalist friend of mine in a couple of days (provincial newspaper, not the nationals), so if I remember, I'll ask him whether they advise on "preferred style" down to this level. FWIW though, my general impression is that over recent decades, BrE has moved more towards reduced punctuation than AmE, so I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out Guardian / London Times writers are told to use ***am***, whereas The New York Times might be still telling people to use ***a.m.***

Comment: I read the _Guardian_ for its political stance, and for the general very high quality of its journalism. I can put up with a few typos and inconsistencies, and there aren't really very many these days.